# Speed Dial 2 How-To: How to Sync Google Chrome Bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, google-bookmarks, speed-dial

I just added the Speed Dial 2 Pro extension to Google Chrome. I'm clueless as to how to sync my Google Chrome Bookmarks. I did get an export file from Google Chrome and tried to import but I don't think it worked. Can someone help? I'm not super techy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you don't need to import / export bookmarks

Comment: You sync your chrome bookmarks by logging in to Chrome. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: See https://www.speeddial2.com/faq and https://www.speeddial2.com/adding-new-bookmarks for info on how to add bookmarks to speed dial pro 2